# Оптимизация работы в IDE Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оптимизировать Eclipse. Пользуюсь на данный момент Eclipse Neon. Жутко лагает и притормаживает. Почти невозможно работать. Скачиваение более ранних версий поможет? Или есть ещё какие-либо способы?

Comment: Оптимизировать наверное надо систему, например установкой SSD. Может помочь например отключение большого количества валидаторов, можно оставить только самые необходимые.

Comment: ОС, железо, конфиг эклипса?

Answer (score 0):

Вполне приемлемо работает eclipse oxygen.2 - 4.7.2. Обновись. Сохрани бекап воркспейса. (если откатится решишь) Версия jre 8. Можно 9 попробовать, говорят должно, но у меня не заработало(сколько мануалов не читал все не то, единственное что не пробывал переустановить с нуля).

Закрой все не используемые проекты и перспективы. Увеличь память для явы в eclipse.ini. Отключи не используемые плагины.

В ини для 6гб, для убунту 64бит у меня: (это все не оптимально, просто показываю как память увеличить, параметры Xms, Xmx)

```
-vm
/home/lenya/Java/jre-1.8.0_162-oracle/bin/
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

**Update:** [Мой похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781795/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-eclipse-4-7-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-server-jre-1-8-oracle-linuxubuntu), с моим же ответом и приложенным конфигом, с комментариями для настройки под свое железо/ось. В комментариях правильно сказали - SSD, даже самый дешевый, не обязательно большой - под систему, и оставить HDD под остальное, workspace на SSD.

Comment: Для начала создайте новый воркспейс, для теста, все должно быть быстро.