# Как сделать Eclipse 4.7 более отзывчивым server-jre-1.8 oracle... Linux(Ubuntu)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, eclipse

Пытаюсь заставить работать Эклипс 4.7 быстрее, не во время загрузки а в процессе длительной работы с ним. По документации настроил G1C для oracle 8.
Настройки по документации для Linux.

Может какие-то файлы вынести на рам диск - те которые не меняются rsyncom, а что-то типа логов просто bind'ом? Какие? Памяти 6гб, Эклипс 2, еще много жрет браузер и средне веб сервер. И гиг на десктоп оболочку.

[мой похожий вопрос с ответом с примером конфиг файла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668001/how-to-make-eclipse-4-7-run-smooth-on-server-jre-1-8-on-linuxubuntu)

Comment: Может от размера проекта зависит или железа... У меня 8Гб ОЗУ, OpenJDK 1.8, Ubuntu 16.04, все настройки по дефолту, ничего не тюнил, ни на что не жалуюсь.

Comment: У меня тоже не медленно было, но удалось ускорить немного. Все равно микроскопические подтормаживания остались, может это так написано.

Comment: Что значит "подтормаживания"? У меня древнючий ноут i5, 2 ядра, 4 потока, 16 Gb памяти, Linux Mint 18.3. Проектов до фига и больше, в одном workspace. И в одном проекте может быть подключено Perl, C/CPP, XML, JS, Java, DBeaver, Git - активные перспективы. Конфиг стандартный. Разве что только частоту проверки синтаксиса "на лету" менял на пореже, вот это точно может сказываться (не холивара ради - JB тут и рядом не валялись...).

Comment: Интерфейс лагал на доли секунды. Самое повторяемое это ховер по нескольком пунктам меню, не все подсвечивались, где- остановились - не выбран. Процессор хуже чем и5, какой-то селерон, 2 ядра, 2ггц.

Comment: Под эклипс выбрал минимум 1гб, максимум 2гб, реально скачет до 1.5гб в процессе, но если нажать кнопку отчистить память то в десятки раз уменьшается, т.е что-то полезное все же хранится в кеше, настроил G1C, так чтоб долгие операции почти не запускались пока есть свободная память, быстрые редко. Немногие параметры оставил G1C на динамическую автонастройку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитал документацию по опциям oracle-jre-8, настроил g1c - меньше микро-притормаживаний но больше памяти, а так-же некоторые другие опции. Выкладываю файл настроек эклипса с комментариями, хоть немного но быстрее работает и комменты позволяют настроить под себя. **Дополнительно** нужно настроить сам Эклипс на более быструю работу, но это есть **в других вопросах-ответах-гугле.**

**Устал экономить на спичках**, купил относительно **дешевый SSD**, из низшей ценовой категории выбрал оптимальный по производителю, заявленной скорости. Эклипс ещё не ставил, но Убунта работает заметно быстрее. Но все равно покопатся в настройках интерестнее, чем посто апгредить железо.

**Если есть что ещё предложить- пишите в комментах, ответах.** По настройкам внутри эклипса на сайте уже есть всё(так же в английской версии стек оверфлоу), по настройке **системы и jre** - неочень.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
#Turn off splash. Better for Ubuntu Unity
-nosplash
#-showsplash
#org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
#
#client or server VM
#-client
-server
-vm
/home/lenya/Java/server-jre-1.8.0_162-oracle/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
#
#Enable the G1 Collector
#Configured for oracle java 8, lower response time
#Using docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseLargePages
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:-DontCompileHugeMethods
-XX:-UseLoopPredicate
-XX:+UseG1GC
#
#This is interpreted as a hint to the garbage collector that pause times of <nnn> milliseconds or less are desired.
#The garbage collector will adjust the Java heap size and other parameters related to garbage collection in an
#attempt to keep garbage collection pauses shorter than <nnn> milliseconds. By default there is no maximum pause
#time goal. These adjustments may cause garbage collector to occur more frequently, reducing the overall throughput
#of the application. The garbage collector tries to meet any pause time goal before the throughput goal. 
#In some cases, though, the desired pause time goal cannot be met.
#__For lower response time - more maximum pause__ __Larger heap needed__
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=5000
#
#The throughput goal is measured in terms of the time spent collecting garbage and the time spent outside of garbage
#collection (referred to as application time). The goal is specified by the command-line option -XX:GCTimeRatio=<nnn>.
#The ratio of garbage collection time to application time is 1 / (1 + <nnn>). For example, -XX:GCTimeRatio=19 sets
#a goal of 1/20th or 5% of the total time for garbage collection.
#
#The time spent in garbage collection is the total time for both the young generation and old generation collections combined.
#If the throughput goal is not being met, then the sizes of the generations are increased in an effort to increase the time
#that the application can run between collections.
# __Larger heap needed__
-XX:GCTimeRatio=99
#
#Sets the Java heap occupancy threshold that triggers a marking cycle.
#Percentage of the (entire) heap occupancy to start a concurrent GC cycle. It is used by G1 to trigger a concurrent GC
#cycle based on the occupancy of the entire heap, not just one of the generations. 
#A value of 0 denotes 'do constant GC cycles'. The default value is 45
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70
#
#Sets the occupancy threshold for an old region to be included in a mixed garbage collection cycle.
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=80
#
#Sets the percentage of heap that you are willing to waste. The Java HotSpot VM does not initiate the 
#mixed garbage collection cycle when the reclaimable percentage is less than the heap waste percentage
-XX:G1HeapWastePercent=10
#
#Sets the target number of mixed garbage collections after a marking cycle to collect old regions with
#at most G1MixedGCLIveThresholdPercent live data. The default is 8 mixed garbage collections.
#The goal for mixed collections is to be within this target number
#-XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=64
#
#Sets an upper limit on the number of old regions to be collected during a mixed garbage collection cycle.
#The default is 10 percent of the Java heap
-XX:G1OldCSetRegionThresholdPercent=5
#
#G1 creates a false ceiling by trying to leave the reserve memory free in case more 'to-space' is desired
#__Ajust depending on heap size__
-XX:G1ReservePercent=15
#
#Sets the percentage of the heap to use as the minimum for the young generation size. The default value is 5 percent of your Java heap
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=5
#Sets the percentage of the heap size to use as the maximum for young generation size. The default value is 60 percent of your Java heap
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=50
#
#Sets the number of parallel marking threads. Sets n to approximately 1/4 of the number of parallel garbage collection threads (ParallelGCThreads).
#Number of threads concurrent garbage collectors will use. 
#The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
#
#Sets the value of the STW worker threads. Sets the value of n to the number of logical processors. 
#Sets the number of threads used during parallel phases of the garbage collectors.
#The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running.
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
#
#With G1 the Java heap is subdivided into uniformly sized regions. This sets the size of the individual sub-divisions.
#The default value of this parameter is determined ergonomically based upon heap size. 
#The minimum value is 1Mb and the maximum value is 32Mb. The goal is to have around 2048 regions based on the minimum Java heap size.
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=1m
#
#Sets the thread stack size.
-Xss16m
#
#Specifies the initial size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.
#__Disable it for auto configuration, changed at run time__
-Xms1g
#
#Specifies the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool.
#__Do avoid swapping__ __Set less, and tune GC__
-Xmx2g
#
#Sets the mode of the bytecode verifier. Bytecode verification ensures that class files are properly formed and
#satisfy the constraints listed in section 4.10, Verification of class Files in the The Java Virtual Machine Specification.
#Do not turn off verification as this reduces the protection provided by Java and could cause problems due to ill-formed class files.
-Xverify:none
```

Update: Сделал новый сервер для разработки, новый эклипс. Сразу чувствуется что памяти ему мало - из дефолтных настроек. Небельшой проект - 1мб пхп и 2мб яваскрипта - постоянно заполняется память, постоянно срабатывает GC, ну и на этом тормоза, не большие совсем но все же.